# if $-\sum_{i=1}^{n}p_{i}\log_{2}{p_{i}}\ge\log_{2}{d}$, then $\max{p_{i}}\le\frac{1}{d}$

Tags: inequality

if the real numbers such $p_{i}>0,i=1,2,\cdots,n$, and 
 $$-\sum_{i=1}^{n}p_{i}\log_{2}{p_{i}}\ge\log_{2}{d}$$ prove or disprove  $$\max{(p_{i})}\le\frac{1}{d}$$

my try:
$$f(x)=-x\log_{2}{x}\Longrightarrow f'(x)=-\left(\log_{2}{x}+\dfrac{1}{\ln{2}}\right)$$
so
$$f''(x)=-\dfrac{1}{x\ln{2}}<0,x>0$$
let $$p_{1}+p_{2}+\cdots+p_{n}=m$$
then 
$$f(\dfrac{p_{1}+p_{2}+\cdots+p_{n}}{n})\le\dfrac{f(p_{1})+f(p_{2})+\cdots+f(p_{n})}{n}$$
so
$$-\sum_{i=1}^{n}p_{i}\log_{2}{p_{i}}\ge nf(\dfrac{m}{n})=-d\log_{2}{\dfrac{m}{n}}$$
then I can't,Thank you

Comment: Do you have other constraints on $p_i, d$? Otherwise a counter e.g. would be $n=3, p_i=\frac12, d=2\sqrt2$.

Answer (score 0):

Idea too long for a comment: when $p_1+\cdots+p_n=1$,
$$H(p_1,\cdots,p_n)=-\sum_{i=1}^{n}p_{i}\log_{2}{p_{i}}$$
is the entropy function, with maximum at $p_i=1/n$, $i=1,\cdots,n$ and
$$H(1/n,\cdots,1/n)=-{n}{1\over n}\log_{2}{{1\over n}}=log_2 n.$$